# jqgrid increase toolbar height

Tags: java, jqgrid

Is it possible to increase the height of the top toolbar for jqgrid?
In PC I can see the button, and select box ok. 
But when viewed in tablet ie andriod ICS and ios 5, the button and select box are truncated at the bottom bec either the height is too short or the padding cause the select box and button to show down alittle.

Using the latest jqgrid 4.3.1

```
<table id="gridmain"></table>
<div id="pagermain"></div>
<script src="Usergrid.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

then in my js file:
I enable toolbar with:

```
toolbar: [true,"top"]
```

then I added some select options and button on the top toolbar with:

```
$("#t_gridmain").append("&nbsp;Status:&nbsp;");
$("#t_gridmain").append("<select name='selStatus' id='selStatus'><option value='All'>All</option><option value='InProgress' selected>InProgress</option><option value='New'>New</option><option value='Passed'>Passed</option><option value='Failed'>Failed</option><option value='Withdrawn'>Withdrawn</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
$("#t_gridmain").append("<input type='button' value='Email' id='buttEmail' style='height:20px;font-size:-4'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
$("#t_gridmain").append("<input type='checkbox' id='showinactive' name='showinactive'/>&nbsp;Show Inactive&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't tested my suggestion, but I suppose, that you can solve the problem by increasing of the  `height` style to any value higher as the default value 25px:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager {
    height: 30px !important;
}
```

**UPDATED**: It you mean top toolbar instead of the top navigation toolbar used more frequently you need

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-userdata {
    height: 30px; /* default value in ui.jqgrid.CSS is 21px */
}
```

Comment: seems didn't do anything. i change the 30px to 100px to see if I can notice any difference but nothing change on the screen.

Comment: @MengHai: To have less misunderstandings it's always good to post some code. After you included in your question `toolbar: [true,"top"]` it would clear what you means. I supposed before that you used `toppager: true` together with `navGrid` or `inlineGrid` and `navButtonAdd`. See the "UPDATED" part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#t_gridmain").css('height', '30px');
```